# React Native: Show runtime errors while compiling (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am using `TypeScript` in my `react-native` project and it works fine. 
The only problem I am having is that, the IDE shows me the errors and everything. But I am still able to run my project even if there are some typescript errors.
For example if I have a typescript error for example

```js
 type something = 'abc'
```

```js
const fn(arg: something){ }
fn('somethingelse')
```

The IDE will show that `somethingelse` is not assigned to `abc`.
But when I Reload the app/bundle. It still compiles.
I have added some of my typescript configuration files

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "app",
    "target": "es2018",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "importHelpers": false,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "include": ["jest"]
  },
  "include": ["app/**/*", "test-utils"]
}
```

And when I also do `yarn tsc` I get this error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined`
Though tsc --w works, But I want these errors at runtime so that I can fix them whenever they occur. Right now I am only seeing these errors on IDE. but it still compiles.

Comment: I have created issue on expo repo https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8273

Comment: is the tsconfig that you are showing generated by expo?